# Finding ocurrences between two list py

Tags: python, list, sorting, indexing

I´m trying to compare 2 lists in py, then get the values repeat, put it in other list, and then get the index of the value in the very first original list, I got this

```
cecosXLS = ["0101", "0000", "0111", "0105"]
cecoManizales = ["0000", "0101", "0111", "0501", "0502"]
valoresCausa = ["795000","850000","140000","1450000"]
for x in range(len(cecoManizales)):
    comunesManizales = []
    temporaList = cecosXLS.copy()
    temporaList.sort()
    cecoManizales.sort()
    for item1, item2 in zip(temporaList, cecoManizales):
        if item1 == item2:
            comunesManizales.append(item1)
for x in range(len(comunesManizales)):
        print(comunesManizales[x])
for x in range(len(comunesManizales)):
    comun = comunesManizales[x]
    indiceComun = cecosXLS.index(comun)
    print(indiceComun)
```

As you can see, I sort the original list, in a new one, to compare with the list I need to, then assign the values of the occurrences in a new list, the problem here is this:

```
Very original list =  ['0101', '0000', '0111', '0105']
Sort of the original list =  ['0000', '0101', '0105', '0111']
List to compare with the original sort =  ['0000', '0101', '0111', '0501', '0502']
List of occurrences in both list =  ['0000', '0101']
```

But the total occurrences are 3 instead of 2, '0000', '0101', '0111' but I can reach the last one, because is not in the same index in both of the sort list, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing

```py
    for item1, item2 in zip(temporaList, cecoManizales):
        if item1 == item2:
            comunesManizales.append(item1)
```

With:

```py
    index = 0
    for item1 in temporaList:
        item2 = cecoManizales[index]
        while item1 > item2:
            index+=1
        if item1 == item2:
            comunesManizales.append(item1)
            index+=1
```

For long lists though, it may be a bit faster to count the objects in each list using a dict instead of sorting them.

Answer (score 1):

I see basically you want to compare the content of two list for elements which are present in both list. There is a pythonic way to do this instead of you going through all elements in a list.

```
def common_member(a, b):   
    a_set = set(a)
    b_set = set(b)
     
    # check length
    if len(a_set.intersection(b_set)) > 0:
        return(a_set.intersection(b_set)) 
    else:
        return("no common elements")

cecosXLS = ["0101", "0000", "0111", "0105"]
cecoManizales = ["0000", "0101", "0111", "0501", "0502"]
common_member(cecosXLS, cecoManizales)
```

The above code should give you all common elements between the two lists

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is that you are looping with zip, which combines the elements from your list like (List1[0], List2[0]), (List1[1], List2[1]), (List1[2], List2[2]). Meaning if List1[0] == List2[1] you will never find it.

Instead, make two for loops, one nested in the other, to make sure you catch all combinations

```py
for item1 in temporaList:
    for item2 in cecoManizales:
        if (item1 == item2) and (not (item1 in comunesManizales)):
            #only add if not added before
            comunesManizales.append(item1)
```

Comment: I find the 3 answers really useful, but to the way I´m making my program, this should be the correct one (The others 2 are correct too, but you know what i mean) thanks to all!